# NullPointerException on this.getPreferences()

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception

```
class PlayerDetails : AppCompatActivity(), View.OnClickListener, TextWatcher {

    val sharedPref = this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) // NPE
    var applicationID = sharedPref.getString("applicationID", null)

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityPlayerDetailsBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_player_details)
        ...
    }
...
```

I'm attempting to create a reference to the default Shared Preferences file of my activity by called `this.getPreferences()`.

The results is giving me a `NullPointerException` - why is this? It's not associated with the UI so it doesn't need to be called after `setContentView()`. Why would the activity be `null` at this point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It's not associated with the UI so it doesn't need to be called after
>   setContentView()

Right, but it must be called after:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
```

because `this` refers to the activity's `Context` and this `Context` is only valid after this call.
So what you can do is change the declaration to:

```
val sharedPref: SharedPreferences? by lazy { this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) }
```

this way `sharedPref` will be initialized the first time it will be used, after the call to `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`.
Read more about [lazy](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#lazy).

Comment: Thanks. However what if I want to refer to the `sharedPref` val before `onCreate()`? (I've updated my code if you'd like to look). Because I want `applicationID` to be a public variable to the whole class.

Comment: applicationID` must be initialized only after sharedPref` is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

The safest place to call this is after `super.onCreate(savedInstnaceState)`.

Answer (score 0):

Move the line inside onCreate after super.onCreate

```
val PREFS_NAME = "com.teamtreehouse.colorsarefun.prefs"
var prefs: SharedPreferences? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            prefs =  = this.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_FILENAME, 0)
            binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_player_details)
            ...
        }
```

Comment: I don't want to move it inside onCreate as I want it to be accessible by other functions inside my activity

Comment: @Zorgan make prefs as class variable and then use this.getSharedPreferences() inside onCreate()

Comment: @Zorgan Pls refere updated code. You can refer "prefs" anywhere in your activity

Answer (score 0):

By doing this.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE) you called inherit method from  AppCompatActivity , Since onCreate is the first callback when activity launched , so things are not set up yet.